# SQL command overloading server

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a very weird situation on a MYSQL query. Running 2 SQL queries separatedelly they are VEEEERY fast, running 2 SQL queries inside of only one, which is basically the same thing, is VEEEERY SLOW!

When I execute the command below it returns 10 results from my database and takes 4 seconds:

```
SELECT a.id FROM aaa a, bbb b WHERE (a.id = 'XXX') OR (a.id = b.id) GROUP BY a.id ASC
```

The command below, which is the same as above but without one conditional, returns 1 result from my database and takes 0.003 seconds!

```
SELECT a.id FROM aaa a, bbb b WHERE (a.id = 'XXX') GROUP BY a.id ASC
```

The command below returns 9 results from my database and takes 0.0025 seconds:

```
SELECT a.id FROM aaa a, bbb b WHERE (a.id = b.id) GROUP BY a.id ASC
```

10 = 9 + 1 so everything is ok. But why using OR it takes so much more time?

Comment: use INNER JOIN instead of selecting multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MySQL but my guess is that MySQL can't optimize the query plan for your first query and therefore does a Cartesian product of both tables.

You can rewrite your query in two ways:

1. Use a left join

   ```
   SELECT a.id 
   FROM aaa a, 
   LEFT JOIN bbb b ON a.id = b.id
   WHERE a.id = 'XXX' OR b.id IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY a.id ASC
   ```
2. Use a nested query

   ```
   SELECT a.id
   FROM aaa a
   WHERE a.id = 'XXX' OR a.id IN(
       SELECT b.id FROM bbb b
   )
   ```

Comment: I tried your 1. and it takes too long to... I have no idea why OR creates this problem... is there a way to execute both queries separeted and have MYSQL to join the returned lines?